# Are there language textbooks which include an epilogue which is understandable once the textbook's contents are mastered?

Tags: resource-request, reading

In a computer RPG game, the character levels up and begins to effortlessly kill monsters that were once a major challenge.  It's a satisfying feeling of progress.

I'm studying Chinese, and no textbook I've encountered has an analogous stage where you effortlessly read material that was once difficult.  I wish there was e.g. an interesting short story at the end of my textbooks ("Congratulations!  Now enjoy this story you can read without further study---you earned it!"); it's the reward for mastering the textbook's contents, and serves to give a feeling of progress.

As proof of concept, I'm wondering if such textbooks even exist in any language:

**Question**: Are there language textbooks which include an epilogue which is understandable once the textbook's contents are mastered?

Comment: Many textbooks (NOT apps) at an advanced level include graded readings. As for mastering a textbook, I find that idea a bit dicey. Language fluency is not determined by "mastering a textbook" but by whether you can read, write, speak and hear it.

Comment: "Teach Yourself Finnish" by Arthur H. Whitney was a novel in which each lesson was increasingly harder. But it doesn't really count as an answer, because new grammar and vocabulary is included in each lesson, and it's generally proceeding rather too quickly for a true beginner.

Answer (score -1):

Try the app Cascade Spanish. It gives you Spanish stories as it teaches you Spanish. The stories it gives you are mostly written using the words it taught you